# Magento saving data in session but in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, magento

**Magento Javascript Question**

Does anyone know how I can call the session singleton in Javascript?
I have a validation to a form like this which, everytime it validates the checkbox element, I want to to update a value in the session model.

```
Validation.add(
    'validate-tax', 'This is only applicable to certain states.', function(v) {
        var dropDown = document.getElementById("billing:region_id").querySelector('option:checked').text;
        if ((dropDown != 'New York' && document.getElementById("billing:tax_exempt").checked == false) || (dropDown == 'New York')) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setYourNameSession($session_value);
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```

But I don't know if this is possible.

**Additional Information**
I want to do a server-side validation on a checkbox. To do this my plan is to see if the value in the session is true or false. Alternatively, I was thinking to check the HTML elements directly from an observer, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Specified this is for magento, whoever marked this is a duplicate, please check to see that the question was not about general differences between client and server

Comment: You can make an ajax call to the server, possibly to a module route with a controller that sets your session variable. But you already know this.

Comment: if anyone is interested in knowing, i got the answer. got the variable from the post variable in the frontcontroller